# How does ngModelChange works without providing model name in ngModel directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

How does `ngModelChange()` works?

> [(ngModelChange) is the @Output of `ngModel` directive. It fires when the model changes. **You cannot use this event without `ngModel` directive**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840735/change-vs-ngmodelchange-in-angular)

but I am not sure, how  does(`ngModelChange`) it works, if I am use `ngModelChange()` event, even i am not [providing model name to `ngModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146374/ngmodel-without-providing-object-in-angular-2).

```
<input #gb type="text" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text" **ngModel**  
 (ngModelChange)="functionName($event)">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, ngModelChange() work without providing model name to ngModel.

cause of this happen, (ngModelChange) is the @Output of ngModel directive.
when insert some value in input that time **emitEvent is become true** which is by default false (so it not fire page load on initial time).

> _this.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });

you can find at  **\@angular\forms\esm5\forms.js  ► line no 3850**

If `emitEvent` is `true`, this
      change will cause a `valueChanges` event on the `FormControl` to be emitted. This defaults
     to true (as it falls through to `updateValueAndValidity`).

If `emitViewToModelChange` is `true`, an ngModelChange event will be fired to update the
      model.  This is the default behavior if `emitViewToModelChange` is not specified.

If `emitModelToViewChange` is `true`, the view will be notified about the new value
     via an `onChange` event.

now question is that why get same value in $event which is inserted in input instead of `ture`, that cause

> FormControl.prototype.setValue = /**

```
function (value, options) {
        var _this = this;
        if (options === void 0) { options = {}; }
        (/** @type {?} */ (this)).value = this._pendingValue = value;
        if (this._onChange.length && options.emitModelToViewChange !== false) {
            this._onChange.forEach(function (changeFn) { return changeFn(_this.value, options.emitViewToModelChange !== false); });
        }
        this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
    };
```

**same file line no 3911 to 3919**

Comment: Is it still valid with Angular 12?

Answer (score 4):

In the [Source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts) `ngModelChange` is just an event emitter.

```
  @Output('ngModelChange') update = new EventEmitter();
```

It fires when the viewToModelUpdate function is executed.

```
viewToModelUpdate(newValue: any): void {
  this.viewModel = newValue;
  this.update.emit(newValue);
}
```

`ngModel` can be anything and does not have a direct link to anything else. In the code it is declared and it is only used in a function called `ngOnChanges`

```
@Input('ngModel') model: any;
```

---

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  this._checkForErrors();
  if (!this._registered) this._setUpControl();
  if ('isDisabled' in changes) {
    this._updateDisabled(changes);
  }

  if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.viewModel)) {
    this._updateValue(this.model);
    this.viewModel = this.model;
  }
}
```

---

I could be wrong here but it looks to me that `ngModel` is not the single source of truth but `this.viewModel` seems to be, because of this `ngModel` does not need a value for `ngModelChange` to work as it opporates seporatetly from the `ngModel` value.

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

you try it without ngModel

```
<select (change)="changed($event)">
     <option *ngFor="let data of allData" [value]="data.id">
           {{data.name}}
       </option>
</select>

changed(e){
   //event comes as parameter and then find data manually
   //by using e.target.data

}

              OR BY ID

 <inputtype="text" #byid (change)="onChange(byid.value)" />
  onChange(title:string){
   alert(title);
   }
```

You can try by passing id into input